# Extend RAID volume size with storcli

Tags: windows, raid, hardware-raid, storcli, extend

I have RAID1 on 2*240GB HDD , witch i changed with 480GB SSD's.
I changed disk 1 , wait for RAID to rebuild, and then change the other. Now I have  240GB RAID over 480GB disks, and cant find a way to extend the volume , so I can use all the space.

```
 .\storcli64.exe /c0/d0 show
CLI Version = 007.1704.0000.0000 Jan 16, 2021
Operating system = Windows Server 2008 R2
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Group Succeeded


[TOPOLOGY][1]

TOPOLOGY :
========

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|DG| Arr| Row| EID:Slot| DID| Type | State| BT|       Size| PDC|  PI| SED| DS3 | FSpace| TR|
|:-|:---|:---|:--------|:---|:-----|:-----|:--|:----------|:---|:---|:---|:----|:------|:--|
| 0| -  | -  | -       | -  | RAID1| Optl | N | 232.830 GB| dflt| N | N  | none| N     | N |
| 0| 0  | -  | -       | -  | RAID1| Optl | N | 232.830 GB| dflt| N | N  | none| N     | N |
| 0| 0  | 0  | 252:0   | 0  | DRIVE| Onln | N | 446.102 GB| dflt| N | N  | none| -     | N |
| 0| 0  | 1  | 252:1   | 2  | DRIVE| Onln | N | 446.102 GB| dflt| N | N  | none| -     | N |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

DG=Disk Group Index|Arr=Array Index|Row=Row Index|EID=Enclosure Device ID
DID=Device ID|Type=Drive Type|Onln=Online|Rbld=Rebuild|Optl=Optimal|Dgrd=Degraded
Pdgd=Partially degraded|Offln=Offline|BT=Background Task Active
PDC=PD Cache|PI=Protection Info|SED=Self Encrypting Drive|Frgn=Foreign
DS3=Dimmer Switch 3|dflt=Default|Msng=Missing|FSpace=Free Space Present
TR=Transport Ready


Drive Information :
=================

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|EID:Slt| DID | State| DG |      Size| Intf|Med| SED |PI| SeSz| Model               | Sp|Type|
|:------|:--- |:-----|:---|:---------|:----|:--|:----|: |:----|:--------------------|:--|:---|
|252:0  |   0 | Onln |  0 |446.102 GB|SATA |SSD| N   |N | 512B| SAMSUNG MZ7L3480HCHQ| U | -  |
|252:1  |   2 | Onln |  0 |446.102 GB|SATA |SSD| N   |N | 512B| SAMSUNG MZ7L3480HCHQ| U | -  |

[Drive Information][2]

[Disk Management][3]
```

Can anyone guide me what tool to use for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Will post here just for someone who try something like this.

[User manual](http://mseas.mit.edu/download/phaley/MegaRAID/2021/MR-TM-StorCLI-UG106.pdf)

> Virtual Drive Expansion Commands The StorCLI utility supports the
> following commands for virtual drive expansion:

```
storcli /cx/vx expand size=<value> [expandarray]



storcli /cx/vx|vall show expansion
```

> The
> detailed description for each command follows.

```
storcli /cx/vx expand size=<value> [expandarray]
```

> This command expands the virtual drive
> within the existing array or if you replace the drives with drives
> larger than the size of the existing array. Although the value
> provided might be in MB, the value of the expanded size is displayed
> based on the nearest possible unit. Depending on the input (value)
> provided by you, storcli recognizes the size from the input provided
> by you and rounds up the size to the nearest percentage of free space
> remaining on the drive group; hence, the actual expanded size can
> differ from the size requested by you. If the expandarray option is
> specified, the existing array is expanded. If this option is not
> specified, the virtual drive is expanded.

```
storcli /cx/vx show expansion
```

> This command shows the expansion information on the virtual
> drive with and without array expansion.
> Input example: `storcli /c0/v0 show expansion`

```
Windows> .\storcli64.exe /c0/v0 show expansion


EXPANSION INFORMATION :
=====================

-----------------------------------------------
VD       Size OCE NoArrExp   WithArrExp Status
-----------------------------------------------
 0 232.830 GB Y   -          213.272 GB -
```

> So I have 213 GB free, and will use 190 of them ( the value provided might be in MB)

```
.\storcli64.exe /c0/v0 expand size=190000 expandarray

CLI Version = 007.1704.0000.0000 Jan 16, 2021
Operating system = Windows Server 2008 R2
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = expansion operation succeeded


EXPANSION RESULT :
================

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
VD       Size FreSpc     ReqSize    AbsUsrSz   %FreSpc NewSize    Status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 232.830 GB 213.272 GB 185.546 GB 185.546 GB      87 418.376 GB -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

VD=Virtual Drive/Logical Drive | Size - Current VD size | FreSpc - Freespace available before expansion
ReqSize - Requested Size | %FreSpc - Requested expansion size in % of available free space
AbsUsrSz - User size rounded to nearest % | NoArrExp - Without Array Expansion
```

> and just to check results again

```
\Windows> .\storcli64.exe /c0/v0 show expansion

EXPANSION INFORMATION :
=====================

---------------------------------------------
VD       Size OCE NoArrExp WithArrExp Status
---------------------------------------------
 0 418.376 GB N   -        -          -
---------------------------------------------

OCE - Online Capacity Expansion | WithArrExp - With Array Expansion
 VD=Virtual Drive | NoArrExp - Without Array Expansion
```